# Should I use InSingletonScope when binding MembershipProvider in NInject?

Tags: dependency-injection, ninject

I am pretty new to the NInject binding, and here is what NInject describes.

- **TransientBehavior**-A new instance of the type will be created each time one is requested.
- **SingletonBehavior**-Only a single instance of the type will be created, and the same instance will be returned for each subsequent request.
- **OnePerThreadBehavior**-One instance of the type will be created per thread.
- **OnePerRequestBehavior**-One instance of the type will be created per web request, and will be destroyed when the request ends.

If I want to bind MembershipProvider to SqlMembershipProvider,  should I use SingletonBehavior since I only need one sql membership provider?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753424

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ASP.Net already provides a static instance of the current membership provider via the static **Membership** class and its static **Provider** property.  The binding would likely be in your Application_Start method and look something like this:

```
Bind<MembershipProvider>()
  .ToMethod(ctx => Membership.Provider);
```

Again, because the **Memberhip.Provider** is a static, it's sort of like a singleton already, so the behavior you try to apply doesn't really matter as much.

By not specifying any behavior in the above snippet, Ninject will default to a transient behavior.  In this sort of a binding, I believe that will amount to calling the lambda that returns **Membership.Provider** every time it needs to inject a **MembershipProvider** type.

I suppose there could be an argument for explicitly specifying a singleton behavior as Ninject would likely "cache" the value returned by the lambda the first time it needs to inject a **MembershipProvider**, in effect saving the overhead of executing the lambda.  I'm not 100% sure that's how Ninject would work in this situation, but it seems reasonable that it would.

All that said, my personal preference would be to use **OnePerRequestBehavior**, this way I know Ninject will call my lambda once for each request.  Not sure it's necessary, but I like the idea of getting the provider from **Membership.Provider** once each request since I suppose you can't make assumptions about how or when **Membership.Provider** get's set, though you could probably find out if you dig enough with Reflector.

```
Bind<MembershipProvider>()
  .ToMethod(ctx => Membership.Provider)
  .Using<OnePerRequestBehavior>();
```

Good luck.  Sorry your question sat out here so long!

Comment: thanks, I was just concerned if the user loggs off and someone else logs on, Ninject wont hold onto the previous user. Could you confirm?