# Custom MembershipProvider: No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-membership, unity-container

I have a custom MembershipProvider class that inherits from MembershipProvider that takes two parameters:

```
public class CustomMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    private readonly ISecurityRepository _securityRepository;
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;

    public CustomMembershipProvider(ISecurityRepository securityRepository, IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        ...
    }

    public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        ...
    }

    ... etc
}
```

The config file for this looks similar to this:

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomMembershipProvider" type="Library.Membership.CustomMembershipProvider" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

This works fine mostly throughout my web application for logging in and logging out. I am using Unity for DI and have the necessary classes setup in my Boostrapper.cs class.

However I recently ran into an issue when I wanted to create a custom User class and called the [Membership.GetUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.getuser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method. I get the following exception when I do:

```
{"No parameterless constructor defined for this object. (C:\\*app path*\\web.config line 43)"}
```

Line 43 in my config file points to the custom membership provider that I posted above. I think that elsewhere the app is using Unity to resolve those parameters but when using the Membership class it doesn't.

Is there any way I can tell the application how to resolve those dependencies or if not is there a way of adding those dependencies to my membership provider without using the concrete implementation?

**EDIT 1:**

Here is the custom User class:

```
public class User : MembershipUser
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastLoggedOnDate { get; set; }
    ...         
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

In my custom membership provider class this is what the GetUser method looks like:

```
public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
{
    return _userRepository.GetUser(username);
}
```

Comment: You haven't posted your custom User Class code? This is where the error is right?

Comment: No, the error is that it can't resolve the custom membership provider class. The User class is a very simple user template with properties (name, email, userid etc)

Comment: What code is in your GetUser method? This is where the error is being thrown correct? You state that in your question `called the Membership.GetUser method. I get the following exception when I do:`

Comment: It never actually gets to that code due to the fact it can't resolve the class. But I will update the post with that code in

Comment: This is painful.. I did it this week. I ended up passing the DI container into the custom MembershipProvider. Saved so much hassle.. but its dirty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you can't inject into the Membership provider via constructor. Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753424/dependency-injection-with-custom-membership-provider)

I implemented a Custom Membership Provider using Ninject and I used the ServiceLocator to get the instance of the service.

```
public class AccountMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{
    private readonly IUsers _users;

    public AccountMembershipProvider()
    {
        _users = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IUsers>();
    }

    public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        return _users.IsValidLogin(username, password);
    }
...
}
```

In your case, you need to get the IUserRepository and ISecurityRepository.

When you wire your Interfaces/services

```
    private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IUsers>().To<UsersService>();
        kernel.Bind<IRoles>().To<RolesService>();

        kernel.Bind<MembershipProvider>().To<AccountMembershipProvider>().InRequestScope();
        kernel.Bind<RoleProvider>().To<AccountRoleProvider>().InRequestScope();

    }
```

You can check a complete example of it working (using Ninject but you can adapt it to Unity) here: https://github.com/lopezbertoni/SampleApp

Hope this helps,

Comment: Again, this puts a dependency of your IOC on your MembershipProvider, which isn't always ideal, for example, if you are building a common library.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful

Answer (score 4):

I also use Unity and implemented a custom membership provider, but used a slightly different approach. Check the code sample:

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines the custom membership provider class.
/// </summary>
public class SsoMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{


    private IApplicationsRepository _appsRepo;
    private IUsersRepository _usersRepo;
    private IMembershipsRepository _membershipsRepo;



    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SsoMembershipProvider"/> class
    /// using injectionConstructor attribute in order to get the repositories needed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="appsRepo">The apps repo.</param>
    /// <param name="usersRepo">The users repo.</param>
    /// <param name="membershipsRepo">The memberships repo.</param>
    [InjectionConstructor]
    public SsoMembershipProvider(IApplicationsRepository appsRepo, IUsersRepository usersRepo, IMembershipsRepository membershipsRepo)
    {
        _appsRepo = appsRepo;
        _usersRepo = usersRepo;
        _membershipsRepo = membershipsRepo;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="SsoMembershipProvider"/> class.
    /// which calls the internal contructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>This is happening due to the fact that membership provider needs a
    /// parametless constructor to be initialized</remarks>
    public SsoMembershipProvider()
        : this(DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IApplicationsRepository>(),
        DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUsersRepository>(),
        DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IMembershipsRepository>())
    { }


}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
public ICustomerRepository CustomerRepository { 
 get { return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ICustomerRepository>(); } 
}
```

and then use

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
    var abc = CustomerRepository.ValidateCustomer(username, password);
}
```